# How to fetch unique geo codes from Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm new to Elasticsearch. I've created the INDEX & inserted some documents by following CURL commands.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/museums?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/museums/doc/_bulk?refresh&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"location": "52.374081,4.912350", "name": "NEMO Science Museum"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"location": "52.369219,4.901618", "name": "Museum Het Rembrandthuis"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"location": "52.371667,4.914722", "name": "Nederlands Scheepvaartmuseum"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"location": "51.222900,4.405200", "name": "Letterenhuis"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"location": "48.861111,2.336389", "name": "Musée du Louvre"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"location": "48.860000,2.327000", "name": "Musée d\u0027Orsay"}
{"index":{"_id":7}}
{"location": "52.374081,4.912350", "name": "NEMO7 Science Museum"}
{"index":{"_id":8}}
{"location": "52.369219,4.901618", "name": "Museum8 Het Rembrandthuis"}
{"index":{"_id":9}}
{"location": "52.371667,4.914722", "name": "Nederlands9 Scheepvaartmuseum"}
{"index":{"_id":10}}
{"location": "51.222900,4.405200", "name": "Letterenhuis10"}
{"index":{"_id":11}}
{"location": "48.861111,2.336389", "name": "Musée11 du Louvre"}
{"index":{"_id":12}}
{"location": "48.860000,2.327000", "name": "Musée12 d\u0027Orsay"}
'
```

If you'll see the curl commands I've made some duplicate documents & inserted those also. Now, I want to fetch all documents having UNIQUE GEO CODES & apply SORT(ASC) on that.

I got one sample CURL command like following.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/museums/_search?size=0&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "aggs" : {
        "rings_around_amsterdam" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "field" : "location",
                "origin" : "52.3760, 4.894",
                "ranges" : [
                    { "to" : 100000 },
                    { "from" : 100000, "to" : 300000 },
                    { "from" : 300000 }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

But, it uses RANGE on that. I just want to fetch only UNIQUE GEO CODES & SORT those in ascending order. I googled also but, whatever I'm getting to fetch UNIQUE documents are works on only TEXT/NUMERIC type documents. Not on GEO CODES type document.

Need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

`curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/museums/_search?size=0&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'`
{

```
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs": {
          "distinct_geo_distance" : {
              "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "location"
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. It's returning the distinct document count. Which in my case is 6. But, I I want the document's data also.